# Correct way to target and style specific child elements in Material-ui wrapper components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is the correct/suggested way to target and style specific child elements in `Material-ui` wrapper components using `makeStyles()`? Do we use the class selectors?

e.g. Targeting the input element of a TextField component I use `& .MuiInput-input`

```
import { makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  foo: {
    '& .MuiInput-input': {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  }
});

export default function () {
  const classes = usePageStyles();

  return (<div>
    <TextField
      id="search"
      label="Search"
      placeholder="Search"
      className={classes.x}
    />
  </div>);
};
```

I know that there are a lot of methods to style components in Material-UI, which is why I am a bit confused which is which. So, I just want to know the standard way to target the child elements. I saw examples in the docs using `'& p'` - does that mean that there is no Material-UI specific way? We just use basic css selectors?

Comment: Yeah that's how you target a sub-element via an element selector. I feel that as a standard way to target.

Comment: @AnanE did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest passing in `InputProps` with an object to the `TextField`.

Something like:

```
const InputProps = {
  className: classes.input,
  color: 'primary'
}
```

Then pass it into TextField:

```
<TextField
  InputProps={InputProps}
>
```